# shinyApp : Getting a folder as input and use the files inside the folder as input of a R function

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm new to shiny, and I'd like to create a basic app, that gets some information from the user, and then run some R codes in the background and saves the result.
(I may end up plotting the result, but that shouldn't be difficult.)
However I have problem using the folder I get as an input.
After running the app I get NA as my output. I also tried list.files instead of path.expand, but same problem.
I'd be grateful if someone can tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong.
p.s. I'd like to use the checkGroup input as well, and user might choose all 3 choices.

Based on shiny examples:

```
source("~myfunction.R")
 ui<-fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
  column(8,
    shinyDirButton("dir", "Chose a directory", "Upload")
  ),
  column(3,
         img(src = "example.png", height = 100, width = 200)
  ))
 ,
  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
           checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", 
                              h3("Check one or all"), 
                              choices = list("Plot" = 1, 
                                             "Cleaning" = 2, 
                                             "CSV" = 3),
                              selected = 1))),
 verbatimTextOutput('rawInputValue'),
 verbatimTextOutput('filepaths')

  )

server<- function(input, output,session) {

  volumes = getVolumes() 
  observe({

    shinyDirChoose(input, "dir", roots = volumes, session = session)

      dir.path <- parseDirPath(c(home = '~'),input$dir)
      output$rawInputValue<-renderText({print(dir.path)})
      all.path<- path.expand(dir.path)
    output$filepaths<-renderText({all.path})

    #  myfunction(all.path)
  })

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the server code, you'd need to move the call to shinyDirchoos **outside** the observer and fix the call to parseDirPath. Something like this should work:

```
server<- function(input, output,session) {

  volumes = getVolumes()

  shinyDirChoose(input, "dir", roots = volumes, session = session)

  observe({

    if(length(input$dir) != 1 ) {
      dir.path <- parseDirPath(volumes,input$dir)
      output$rawInputValue<-renderText({dir.path})
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: For ref: shinyDirChoose will not work in server. Like after publishing/deploy it will show server side folder. If you still want this you can use JavaScript for this. Most of the case for security reason from browser it has been blocked but by coding you can do it.

Comment: I ended up using tags so that my code works both locally and on the server side. Is there a way to save the files ( some.Rdata, and plots) without plotting it on shiny App, and saving it on the server or locally ?

Comment: I needed to use volumes() instead of volumes on shinyDirChoose function to make the code work...